# String data type in sqlite

Tags: string, sqlite, types

I created a table as follows:

```
create table employers (
    id integer primary key,
    name string,
    surname string,
    description string
);
```

I noticed [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) that `string` is not between data types, should I replace it with something else? Is it alias for some other datatype? What is the maximum number of characters that can this string contain?

I used `string` and it does not make any problems. I'm only interested how is it possible, that I could use string. Is it some alias? What are the possibilities of this type?

thank you

Answer (score 13):

You want to use TEXT which we use whatever it needs to in order to hold your data.

```
CREATE TABLE Employers (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    surname TEXT,
    description TEXT
);
```

See http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html and note:

> SQLite uses a more general dynamic
>   type system. In SQLite, the datatype
>   of a value is associated with the
>   value itself, not with its container.
>   The dynamic type system of SQLite is
>   backwards compatible with the more
>   common static type systems of other
>   database engines in the sense that SQL
>   statement that work on statically
>   typed databases should work the same
>   way in SQLite. However, the dynamic
>   typing in SQLite allows it to do
>   things which are not possible in
>   traditional rigidly typed databases.

That noted:

> SQLite does not impose any length
>   restrictions (other than the large
>   global SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the
>   length of strings, BLOBs or numeric
>   values.

Finally:

> Maximum length of a string or BLOB
>
> The maximum number of bytes in a
>   string or BLOB in SQLite is defined by
>   the preprocessor macro
>   SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. **The default value
>   of this macro is 1 billion (1 thousand
>   million or 1,000,000,000).** You can
>   raise or lower this value at
>   compile-time using a command-line
>   option like this:
>
> -DSQLITE_MAX_LENGTH=123456789 The current implementation will only
>   support a string or BLOB length up to
>   231-1 or 2147483647. And some built-in
>   functions such as hex() might fail
>   well before that point. In
>   security-sensitive applications it is
>   best not to try to increase the
>   maximum string and blob length. In
>   fact, you might do well to lower the
>   maximum string and blob length to
>   something more in the range of a few
>   million if that is possible.
>
> During part of SQLite's INSERT and
>   SELECT processing, the complete
>   content of each row in the database is
>   encoded as a single BLOB. So the
>   SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH parameter also
>   determines the maximum number of bytes
>   in a row.
>
> The maximum string or BLOB length can
>   be lowered at run-time using the
>   sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_LENGTH,size)
>   interface.

Comment: What about VARCHAR - is it 100% equivalent to TEXT in SQLite? I seek to unify SQL (incl DDL) code for MySQL and SQLite as far as possible without side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your field as "TEXT" and I believe you can specify a length restriction.

so you can declare name TEXT(255) as a 255 character TEXT value.

Comment: Great, it's that simple. Why is this information so hard to find. Thanks.

Comment: Actually in SQLite3, Text(255) won't give you any length checking which means you can still store more than 255 characters.